# Memory Caching architecture

Tags: java, caching, memory-management, architecture, memcached

I am implementing a memory caching system for a web application. This memory caching system will have to handle objects sized from small scale to large scale and more and more hits to caches (reads and writes) . The system will have to handle multiple cachinng services such as JCS, ehCach, Memcach, SQL caching etc based on the configuration.

For learning and studying purposes and to implement a better architecture for my system, any one please let me have some resources. (example: sample class diagrams with project source files ).

Answer (score 1):

The question is totally unspecific! The best thing you can do is to work through the tutorials, examples and manuals of the caching solutions.

You should also consider distributed caching solutions like infinispan and hazelcast.

For in-memory only caching Guava Cache and [cache2k](http://cacke2k.org) (I work on cache2k) might be sufficient.

If you start a new architecture around caching I strongly suggest that you look into the JSR107/JCache spec, because this is the new standard way to access caching services.

Comment: Thanks cruftex for your answer. As you mentioned, I went through some tutorials and examples. But like all of them, they represented coding samples that shows how to use caching services not a good enough architectural level solutions.

Comment: Moho, I see your point. Maybe I should write a book on this?! Maybe you can reformulate your question and/or narrow it down a bit. Now, it includes everything from edge servers, load balancing, down to database persistence...